# Pass data between ajax and controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This code shows nothing as a result. I want to pass a variable from ajax to the controller and then find the value from the model and pass it to ajax; And I want show a message like in the code.

View - test_view.php

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btnclick").click(function(){

            var cname=$("#txt_uname").val();

             //alert(cname);

              $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"http://localhost/NPOS/test/nameget",
                     data:{txt_uname : cname},
                        success:function(data){
                        if(data==0){
                            $("#message").html("<font color='#55DF00'>Name Available</font>");
                        }
                        else{
                            $("#message").html("<font color='#FF0000' >Name Already taken</font>");
                        }
                    }
                 });

            });

         });

       </script>
    <input type="text" name="txt_uname" id="txt_uname"/>
    <input name="btnclick" type="button" id="btnclick" value="Search">
```

Controller - test.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {

      public function index()
      {
           $this->load->view('test_view');
          }


 function nameget()
    {   $this->load->model('test_model');
        $name= $this->input->post('txt_uname'); 
        $find=$this->test_model->nameget($name);

    }
}

?>
```

model - test_model.php

```
class Test_Model extends CI_Model
{

        function nameget($name)
    {
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * from countries where country_name='$name'");
          return $query->result();
    } 
}
```

Comment: data should be in JSON format like  `data:{'txt_uname':txt_uname},`

Comment: Maybe you're not getting a result because you're not using **fail**. Try to add "fail: function(data) {}" after success and see if the request is giving an error

Answer (score 1):

Use this Ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btnclick").click(function(){

            var cname=$("#txt_uname").val();

            //alert(cname);

            $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>test/nameget",
                data:{txt_uname : cname},
                success:function(data){
                    if(data==0){
                        $("#message").html("<font color='#55DF00'>Name Available</font>");
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#message").html("<font color='#FF0000' >Name Already taken</font>");
                    }
                }
            });

        });

    });

</script>
```

> Data sending and URL changed

Opz forget this

In model

```
function nameget($name)
{
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * from countries where country_name='$name'");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in header for ajax code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btnclick").click(function(){
            var BASE_PATH='<?php echo base_url() ?>';
            var cname=$("#txt_uname").val();
            $.post(BASE_PATH+"test/nameget",{txt_uname:cname},function(data){
                    if(data==1){
                         $("#message").html("<font color='#FF0000' >Name Already taken</font>");
                    }else{
                         $("#message").html("<font color='#55DF00' >Name Available</font>");
                    }
            });

        });
});
```

In controller add this function

```
//Function in controller for call model function and return the response
function nameget(){
    $this->load->model('test_model');
    $txt_uname=$this->input->post('txt_uname');
    $check_availablity=$this->test_model->nameget($txt_uname);
    if($check_availablity==TRUE){
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo 0;
    }
}
```

Add this below function in model :

```
//Function in model for fetch data from table
function nameget($txt_uname=''){
    if($txt_uname=='') 
        return false;
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('countries');
    $this->db->where(array('country_name'=>$txt_uname));
    $recordSet = $this->db->get();
    $data=$recordSet->result() ;
    if(count($data)>0)
    {
        return true;
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```